# Node.js Mongodb Not Saving Object Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot with node.js and MongoDB, trying to make an inventory system along with an item shop. Here's my index code (I apologize for its primitive and disorganized appearance, this is just a prototype to get things working):

```
const fs = require("fs");
prefix = config.prefix;

const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    disableEveryone: true,
});

client.logger = require('./modules/Logger');
const moment = require("moment");
unidecode = require('unidecode');

//mongoose connection
mongoPass = config.mongoPass;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(mongoPass, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
console.log("Connected to db!")
const Data = require("./models/data");

client.on ("message", (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    user_ID = message.author.id
    Data.findOne({
        userID: user_ID
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        if(!data){
            if (message.content.startsWith(prefix+"start")) {
                const newData = new Data({
                    userID: user_ID,
                    coins: 0,
                    rank: "Insert Rank",
                    level: 0,
                    xp: 0,
                    rankPoints: 0,
                    currentRobot: {},
                    currentCrew: {},
                    storyModeData: {
                        phase: 0
                    },
                    inventory: {
                        1:{
                            id:"C111",
                            name:"Starter Crew Mate"
                        }
                    },
                    savedLoadouts: {},
                    numberOfOwned: 1
                })
                newData.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
                message.channel.send("Welcome to the FTC RPG!")    
                return;
            }

        } else {
            if (data) {

                var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
                items = require("./shopItems/store")
                item = items[args[0]]
                if (!item){
                    message.channel.send("Item not found")
                } else {
                    if (data.coins > item.price || data.coins == item.price){
                    itemNumber = parseInt(data.numberOfOwned) + 1
                    data.inventory[itemNumber] = item
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(item))
                    console.log(data.inventory)
                    data.numberOfOwned += 1

                    data.save().catch(err => console.log(err));

                    message.channel.send("Item bought successfully!")

                    } else {
                        message.channel.send("You dont have enough to buy this item!")
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    })
});

client.login (config.token);
```

And here is the inside of my "models/data.js" file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    userID: String,
    coins: Number,
    rank: String,
    level: Number,
    xp: Number,
    rankPoints: Number,
    currentRobot: Object,
    currentCrew: Object,
    storyModeData: Object,
    inventory: Object,
    savedLoadouts: Object,
    numberOfOwned: Number

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Data", dataSchema);
```

And the inside of the "shopItems/store.js" file:

```
exports.s0000 = {
    generation: "0",
    price: 1,
    slot:"attachment-1",
    name:"test-store-arm",
    rarity:"storebought",
    level:1,
    xp:0,
    id:"p0000",
    attributes:{
        attribute1:{
            name:"yeet",
            description:"yeet",
            directory:"yeet.js"
        }
    },
    stats:{
        strength:5,
        speed:5
    },
    statgains:{
        strength: "level",
        speed: "level"
    }
}

exports.info = {
    items: "yeet arm"
}
```

So, when testing the code:

There is already a document for my user data saved within the database, which looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("(the id)")
userID:"(my user id)"
coins:16
rank:"Insert Rank"
level:1
xp:4
rankPoints:0
storyModeData:Object
    phase:0
inventory:Object
    1:Object
        id:"C111"
        name:"Starter Crew Mate"
numberOfOwned:13
__v:0
```

And when I remove that document and use the start command to re-enter it, it saves it just fine, with the "starter crewmate" object saved properly
But when I use the command "(prefix).buy s0000", it tells me that it was bought successfully. It looks to be right inside the console as well when it logs after I use that command. It logs the following:

```
{"generation":"0","price":1,"slot":"attachment-1","name":"test-store-arm","rarity":"storebought","level":1,"xp":0,"id":"p0000","attributes":{"attribute1":{"name":"yeet","description":"yeet","directory":"yeet.js"}},"stats":{"strength":5,"speed":5},"statgains":{"strength":"level","speed":"level"}}
{
  '1': { id: 'C111', name: 'Starter Crew Mate' },
  '14': {
    generation: '0',
    price: 1,
    slot: 'attachment-1',
    name: 'test-store-arm',
    rarity: 'storebought',
    level: 1,
    xp: 0,
    id: 'p0000',
    attributes: { attribute1: [Object] },
    stats: { strength: 5, speed: 5 },
    statgains: { strength: 'level', speed: 'level' }
  }
}
```

It will update the "numberOfOwned" variable, and each time I use the command and then refresh the collection view, that variable goes up by one, but the inventory never changes, it remains with just the:

```
inventory:Object
    1:Object
        id:"C111"
        name:"Starter Crew Mate"
```

It can save an object to the user data, as shown by the starter crewmate saving, it can update the data as shown by the numberOfOwned being updated to the db, and it seems to be able to properly save the new item to the inventory as logged in the console. I'm at a loss, anyone know what's wrong?

-Edit: I thought of a slightly inefficient way to add values to the inventory. I figured, if I set a variable equal to data.inventory, then edited that new variable, then basically paste the variable into the data.inventory (setting data.inventory equal to this modified variable). But this didn't work and the inventory variable stayed the same.
After much experimenting and testing, I have found a few weird things about the behavior of the database:
One of the tests I did was defining the value of "data.inventory" in different ways.

Method 1:

```
data.inventory.c3 = "functional"
data.inventory.c4 = "functional"
```

Method 2:

```
data.inventory = {
    c3: "functional",
    c4: "functional"
}
```

I ran both, one after the other, and added a log right after each to see what the resulting value was, that it was setting the inventory to. Both console logs turned out exactly the same, to the letter. Both defined within curly brackets. But when tested individually, only one of them actually got updated to the database, and that was method 2.
So then I was like, hey this could be the fix I'm looking for (because I could set a variable equal to the inventory variable, edit this new variable, then set the inventory equal to this variable), but nope. For some reason, it refuses to save it if I put its value as a variable, but if the object and its inner values are explicitly stated, then it will save for whatever reason.